# Rails 7 - picking up assets automatically in dev doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

For some unknown reason Rails 7 (development environment) doesn't pick up changes in `application.js` automatically when I hit F5 in the browser. The location `application.js` is default. I'm using pretty much default setup.

When I run the server, it picks up javascript from some cached version. I need to explicitly `rails assets:precompile` to make it work.

Importmap looks standard:

```
# Pin npm packages by running ./bin/importmap

pin "application", preload: true
...
```

And layout file seems pretty standard as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Whatever</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= image_path('favicon.svg') %>">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
  </head>
...
```

I tried to set `config.importmap.sweep_cache = true` in my `development.rb` (as per importmap docs), but it seems there is no effect.

At this point I'm pretty desperate and can't understand why do I need to `rails assets:precompile` on my development environment.

Also, I'm not running my app on "localhost" domain, it's on something like `dev.server-somewhere.com` (so it's accessible from anywhere) with SSH redirects, similar to ngrok. Not sure if it's the cause of a problem.

For clarification: I'm looking for no LIVE refresh feature, just the standard approach with F5 page refresh would work.

Comment: Are you using strictly importmaps to handle the javascript or are you using jsbundling or webpack?

Comment: Only importmaps

Answer (score 20):

I have same problem, simply use: `rails assets:clobber` to clear all precompiled assets. After that the hot reloading will start working again.

if existing precompiled JS assets exist in `public/assets/` rails gives them a priority even in development mode (and even when, for example, esbuild or tsc-watch is otherwise working to transpile your source files into `app/assets/buils/`, which is unrelated to Sprocket hanging onto its old cache)

Comment: This works, if I then run `rails assets:precompile` AND then restart my server. But that's a very painful way to develop e.g. Stimulus controllers.

Comment: thanks, I just did rails assets:clobber , this command will delete /public/assets folder and now it' monitor also js files (including stimulus controllers), and I don't have to do precompile.

Comment: After refreshing, I experience the same problem again.

Answer (score 9):

Normally, assets are "precompiled" only in production/deployed environments. That means that by default there shouldn't be a folder at `public/assets/` while you develop (Sprockets compiles assets on-the-fly for you in development mode).

If you accidentally have run `rails assets:precompile` in development, you'll have an extra folder here (`public/assets/`) which does not get checked in to your repository.

But if it does exist, then its existence overrides Sprocket's development mode setting to recompile on every pageload, forcing your browser to load the already compiled (and ***stale***) asset from `public/assets/`...

(Ironically, running `rails assets:precompile` or `rake assets:precompile`, while it does force a one-time recompile and seemingly gives you your latest JS compile, doing this in development is typically what *causes* the problem of Sprockets getting stuck in the first place)

Next, force Sprockets to both delete the `public/assets/` folder and then bust the thumbprint cache using:

```
rails assets:clobber
```

(alternatively, run `rails assets:clean` and then `touch tmp/restart.txt`)

To debug further, set `assets.debug = true` in your environment file.

Comment: I was struggling a bit but what Jason suggested was currently.  Removing the public/assets from clobber is correct and don't need to run precompile locally.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue today and I replaced the sprockets with the [propshaft](https://github.com/rails/propshaft). Then it worked! You might look at the [upgrade guide](https://github.com/rails/propshaft/blob/main/UPGRADING.md).

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue today and simply reverted back to [Sprockets](https://github.com/rails/sprockets) and everything worked out of the box after installing the gem. It seems that [Sprockets is now optional in Rails 7](https://www.mintbit.com/blog/rails-7-dot-0-makes-sprockets-an-optional-dependency). I don't know if Sprockets can be combined with Import Maps, though.